# Pass argument starting with minus sign to shell command

Tags: linux, bash, kde-plasma

I want to run the following (KDE specific) command with an argument (-0.1) that starts with '-'

```
kdialog --textinputbox 'Output:' '-0.1'
```

It is suposed to show a textbox with '-0.1' but the command gives

```
unknown option "-0.1"
```

while

```
kdialog --textinputbox 'Output:' '0.1'
```

works. 
Obviously the command tries to interpret 0.1 as an option.
Is there a way to pass the argument "-0.1" to such commands? I tried passing it as variable which didn't work either!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try with:

```
kdialog --textinputbox 'Output:' -- '-0.1'
```

`--` means "end of options" and should work for all Qt (thus KDE) apps that use the standard argument functions for that framework.